# Sending data between QGIS and other programs in real time

Tags: qgis-plugins

I would like to be able to grab information about QGIS users' interactions and send things like cursor position and button events to a separate program running concurrently in MacOS. With GRASS tools I could use the Unix Pipe for this. Is it possible to do a similar thing with QGIS? Or is there a better way to get information from QGIS to a concurrent program? (We'll be writing a Python plug-in to capture the data within QGIS.)